# How to use a sidebar with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I would like to know how I can create a window with the sidebar, basically what I want is a sidebar that will open some windows by clicking on a name, as in the example below, thanks in advance.
[image: zikoA.gif]

Comment: What application is this?  Rotating through sidebar tabs is easy enough using GUI scripting, but the implementation depends on the application being targeted.

Comment: @TedWrigley This example app is CleanMyMac, I would like to use Sidebar for simple things, I like how things are done with sidebar mainly with CleanMyMac wanted to know a simple way to do this using AppleScript.

Comment: @TedWrigley, Can you help me with this?
I just want to scroll through 5 screens.

Comment: Yeah, I can do it, and I'll post an answer for the CleanMyMac app in a little bit, but you should be aware that the code will be somewhat different for every app you try it with. There's no universal answer. I'll explain in the post.

Comment: @Ted wrigle, any news?

Comment: Well, playing with this a bit it seems to me that if you want a proper sidebar you're going to have to use (at the very least) a cocoa-applescripts app, or (better) build the app in Xcode. Vanilla AppleScript does not handle callbacks well, which makes things like delegates and target/action impossible. You could *display* a sidebar in AppleScript, but you couldn't really implement its functionality. If you're willing to compromise, I could set up a tab view: same functionality of displaying a sequence of views, but with a different appearance.

Comment: @TedWrigley, I'm actually using Xcode for this,
I really wanted to try a sidebar I think it's elegant,
would you use table view cell or something similar for that?
what would be the best approach?

Comment: Ah, if you're using Xcode hat makes things much more palatable. Let me see what I can do this afternoon.

Comment: @TedWrigley, ok, thanks advance. Edit: What I want to do is something like Tab View, but using sidebar so I can select with both mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here are the steps for setting up a sidebar in an Xcode AppleScript app. I'm just showing functionality; I'll leave beautification for you to play with.

First (obviously), set up the GUI. Open MainMenu.xib, and add three items from the object library:

- A Table View in the left side of the window (to display the sidebar)
- A Custom View in the right side of the window (to display a detail view)
- An Array Controller in the objects list on the left.

It should look something like this (red annotation for clarity):[image: GUI pic]
You'll want to set up layout constraints to keep the sidebar a constant width and keep the custom view glued to its side, but you can play with that.

Now we'll set up bindings and a few other details. First, click of the Array Controller object on the left, and open the Utilities pane on the right.

- Click the 'Attributes' inspector.

  - Make sure the Mode is 'class' and the 'class name' is NSMutableDictionary
  - Add two names to the 'Keys' section: 'title' and 'isHeader' (these are the keys we'll be using in the dictionaries)
  - Unclick 'Select inserted objects', because it's annoying.

Next, click on the Table View in the list, then go again to the Utilities pane on the right.

- Click the 'Attributes' inspector and set the number of columns to 1.
- Click the 'Bindings' inspector, go down to the Table Content section, and create two bindings:

  - In **Content** click the *Bind to* checkbox, choose *Array Controller* from the popup, and make sure that the Controller Key is *arrangedObjects*
  - In **Selection Indexes** make the same object binding but use *selectionIndexes* for the Controller Key.
- Click the 'Connections' inspector, and drag from the delegate outlet to the Delegate object on the left, so that the table view will use the AppDelegate script as its table view delegate.

Next, click on the Table Cell View in the list, and again to the Utilities pane.

- Click the 'Identity' inspector and set the identifier to 'tableItem' (without the quotes). This lets the delegate find this particular view and pass it on to the table.

Finally, click on the Table View Cell object on the left (*not* the Table Cell View object just above it, or the second Table View Cell just below it: confusing, I know), and go to the Utilities pane on the right, again.

- Click the 'Bindings' inspector, go to the Value section at top, and create one binding:

  - In **Value** click the *Bind to* checkbox, choose *Table Cell View* from the popup, leave the Controller Key blank, and set the Model Key Path to *objectValue.title*

The way this works is that we'll dump a list of dictionaries into the Array Controller, the Table View will pick that up and dole out one dictionary to each Table Cell View as its objectValue, and then the Table View Cells will extract the data and present it.

We're done with the GUI, except for connecting it the script. Now, go to the AppDelegate script that Xcode provided, and you'll want to change it to look like so:

```
script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value
    property arrayController : missing value
    property detailView : missing value

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
        (* set up list of headers and lines for the side bar *)
        set sidebarList to {{title:"Header 1", isHeader:true}, {title:"Line 1", isHeader:false}, {title:"Header 2", isHeader:true}, {title:"Line 2", isHeader:false}, {title:"Line 3", isHeader:false}, {title:"Header 3", isHeader:true}, {title:"Line 4", isHeader:false}}
        arrayController's addObjects:sidebarList
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_

    (* table view delegate emthods *)

    on tableView:tableView isGroupRow:row
        -- header rows are group rows
        set rowData to arrayController's arrangedObjects's objectAtIndex:row
        return rowData's isHeader
    end

    on tableView:tableView shouldSelectRow:row
        -- don't want to select header rows
        set rowData to arrayController's arrangedObjects's objectAtIndex:row
        return not (rowData's isHeader)
    end

    on tableView:tableView viewForTableColumn:column row:row
        -- header rows get a special look
        set aView to tableView's makeViewWithIdentifier:"tableItem" owner:me
        return aView
    end

    on tableViewSelectionDidChange:aNotification
        (* 
         This is method gets notified right after a selection is made. This is one of 
         the places where you can change the detail view to show a the correct view for 
         selected sidebar item. For demonstration purposes I'm just swapping out 
         TextField views with the name of the sidebar item. Not to sophisticated, 
         but it get the point across
         *)
        set tableView to aNotification's object
        set selectedRowIdx to (tableView's selectedRow) as integer
        set rowData to arrayController's arrangedObjects's objectAtIndex:selectedRowIdx
        set newLabel to current application's NSTextField's labelWithString:(rowData's title )
        set newLabel's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false
        set detailSubviews to (detailView's subviews) as list
        if detailSubviews is not {} then
            set oldLabel to item 1 of detailSubviews
            detailView's replaceSubview:oldLabel |with|:newLabel
        else
            detailView's addSubview:newLabel
        end

        set constraintX to newLabel's centerXAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(detailView's centerXAnchor)
        set constraintY to newLabel's centerYAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(detailView's centerYAnchor)
        constraintX's setActive:true
        constraintY's setActive:true
    end

end script
```

I added two properties — arrayController and detailView, both with the value 'missing value' (which indicates they are IBOutlets) — that we'll link up to the GUI. I've added two lines in `applicationWillFinishLaunching_` to create a list of records and add it to the Array Controller, and the rest are delegate methods that the Table View calls.

To link up the GUI, go back to MainMenu.xib, click on the Array Controller object, open the 'Connections' inspector in the Utilities pane, and drag a New Referencing Outlet to the Delegate object, connecting it with the property *arrayController*. Do the same for the Custom View, connecting it to the property *detailView*. You should be good to go.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm not being clear here, I would like to create an application with sidebar, the example you gave me and for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, yeah, I didn't get that from your post. You want to create a window with a sidebar in AppleScript, is that it?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a window with sidebar, I'm sorry if I was not very clear.

Comment: Could you rewrite the question to make that clearer?

Comment: Thanks for your hard work, I'll try this tomorrow and post the results here.

Comment: It works, but I notice some things missing
maybe my fault, for example the "title" are not showing
and the space between one end is strange, was it any configuration that I made wrong?
else i need to know how to work using this with other .xib files or is there a way to use only one for all
screens? I believe not, thank you if you can help me with any of these questions.

Comment: [sidebar.gif](https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/08/12/sidebar.gif)](https://imgbbb.com/image/p6GtF)

Comment: @TheOnlyOneHere - ok, that gif tells me that something is off with the 'Table View Cell' binding. The TVC should be bound to the Table Cell View, with the Model Key objectValue.title; the Array Controller should have a key called 'title' in the attributes pane, and the records in the `applicationWillFinishLaunching_` method of the appDelegate should use the key 'title'. Case matters, so make sure you didn't accidentally throw in a capital letter or make some other typo.

Comment: A quirk of IB in Xcode. When you change a text value in one of the inspector panes, make sure you hit return, or click in one of the other text fields. Xcode won't actually incorporate the text into the xib until you take an action like that, so if you build and run before you do, the field will *look* correct, but the value won't actually be used in the build. Very annoying...

Comment: I will follow the steps again, let you know.

Comment: I follow the steps again paying attention
every detail, but failed again, follows the project link.
Please tell me where I am failing. https://www.sendspace.com/file/kqi6z9

Comment: @TheOnlyOneHere -  Oops, I see the problem. I forgot to include an instruction.  Go to MainMenu.xib, click on *Table Cell View", open the Identity inspector, and set the identifier filed to 'tableItem'. I'd forgotten I used that identifier in the `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` delegate method, so the delegate couldn't find the right view. I'll add that to the instructions above. That wasn't strictly necessary with only one cell view, but it's (generally) good practice.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you bound the 'title' key a little oddly. There are three levels here — Table Cell View -> Table View Cell -> (another) Table View Cell — corresponding roughly to the view (that connects the element to other views), the control (that sets up the element's visual functionality), and the control's cell (that handles the inner work of the element).   Traditionally bindings get set on the control (the second level) not the cell (the third level). Both work, so it doesn't *really* matter (at least in most cases), but if you work as part of a team it might confuse people.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Yd14KZh, working like a charm, Now I need to know how should I work with screens, so that in each of them I have specific elements, I must use several .xib? if so how can i do this?

Comment: This isn't really the right forum for a discussion of this detail. is there someplace else we can take this up?

Comment: I understand, do you have any suggestions in mind? maybe macScripter? e-mail?

Comment: I have MacScripter account that I haven't used in a while, but it really depends on what your goal is. Do you just have a couple more questions, or do you need someone to help you through an entire development process?

Comment: I need with both 

Comment: Could you help me with some questions throughout the development process?

Comment: I think I see the thread you're on over at MacScripter. We'll talk there.

Comment: could you send me a PM
In MacScripter, I couldn't find you there.

Comment: Under what user name?

Comment: see [this thread](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=197241#p197241)

Comment: Could you tell me how to add custom icons to the left
of each title?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [sidebar / source list](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/sidebars/) - you can take a look at Apple’s older [SidebarDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010893) sample project for an example of something fairly small using an outline view (might even be relatively easy to translate to ASObjC).

Depending on what you are ultimately wanting to do, I suppose it could be done with AppleScript, but I think you will find that the bigger the application, the bigger a pain it is.   AppleScript is great for prototyping and controlling other applications, but not so much when things start getting large or complex (e..g. your previous experiences with sheets).  If you are planning on doing applications that are a bit more serious, you might look into using a language that is also a bit more serious.

Comment: I would really like to know a simple way to use sidebar in AppleScript, regarding the sheets I am still facing some difficulties, but I will ask you in the appropriate topic later.