# MacOS: How to update an AppDelegate property via editing a table view cell?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, appdelegate, cocoa-bindings

In my macOS app I’m trying to update an AppDelegate property by editing a Table View Cell.

I created a sample project (Table View example project with array controller) using tips from the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384941/how-to-use-a-sidebar-with-applescript/57405652#57405652).

I’m using macOS Big Sur (11.6.8) and Xcode 12.5.1. I'll be glad to supply a source archive download link or email it if requested. When I tried to add a link in this post it was rejected.

```
Here's my AppDelegate script:
```

```
    script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    property msg : ""

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value
    property tableViewData : missing value
    property arrayController : missing value
    property showTableViewData : missing value
    
    on `applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)`     
    appInit()
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
    
    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_
    
    on appInit()
        
    set my msg to (current date & return & return & "Initializing…") as string
    delay .5
    initTableView()
    set my msg to (current date & return & return & "Ready.") as string
    delay .5
        
    end appInit
    
    on initTableView()
    
    set my tableViewData to {}
    set my tableViewData to {{adName:("C21 ad" as string), pageNumber:("001" as string)}, {adName:("ERA ad" as string), pageNumber:("002" as string)}}

    end initTableView
    
    on `showTableViewData_(sender)`

    set my msg to (current date & return & return & "showing tableViewData....") as string
    delay .5

    set displayText to ""
    repeat with thisRecord in tableViewData
            
    display alert "adName: " & (adName of thisRecord as  string) & return & "pageNumber: " & (pageNumber of thisRecord as  string)

    end repeat
        
    set my msg to (current date & return & return & "Ready.") as string
    delay .5

    end `showTableViewData_`

    end script
```

How it works

As you can see I have hardcoded two records which I use to populate the tableViewData property on initialization which in turn is displayed in the table view. For some reason the adName data is not being displayed, but that bug is not what this post is about.

[App initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhRyg.jpg)

Clicking the button reads the tableViewData property, iterates the records displaying them via an alert (so we can see it's contents).

[Record display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwNN6.jpg)

Aside from the adName not displaying, so far so good.

Next, I edit the pageNumber table view cell for the first record (changing it from "001" to "777" *and hitting return*). **When I click the button the first record is displayed which still shows a pageNumber value of "001" (instead of the "777" value I entered).**

[Record display after editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E5ZH.png)

Here are some shots of the table view cell attributes, connections, and bindings:

[Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plV02.png)
[Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j4bp.jpg)
[Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKE0O.jpg)

I tried selecting the bindings setting "Continuously Updates Value" but that doesn't seem to help; my tableViewData property is not updated with the newly entered data in the table view cell.

Most of the current developer docs use Obj-C or Swift instead of AppleScript and iOS or tvOS related. I'm using Xcode 12.5.1 because of problems binding UI elements to my code.

Thanks for taking the time to look this over.

Comment: "Most of the current developer docs use Obj-C or Swift instead of AppleScript" And so should you. There isn't _anything_ about your example that requires AppleScript, and ASObjC, while ingenious, is basically a dead letter at this point.

Comment: Try a script object instead of a data record.

Comment: @Willeke - Thanks for the suggestion. I figured my App Delegate script was a script object. I guess I could try loading an additional script file. I was hoping to avoid bridge issues, but might try Bridge+ if I go that route. But again: if my property data is populating the table view cell; shouldn't the reverse also work? I mean weren't bindings meant to reduce the amount of coding necessary?

Comment: @matt - Understood. In this case I'm just adding a couple of minor features to a much larger existing project. I created this sample project to isolate my question and code. That said, if this were a bindings issue, wouldn't the solution pretty much apply to to any language I chose to use? My property data is populating the table view cell; shouldn't the reverse also work?

Comment: It looks like the array controller is using a copy, inspect `content of arrayController`. A [Script Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-BAJJCIAA) does work in my test project. Bindings use KVO, is a list of AppleScript records KVO compliant?

Comment: @Willeke Sorry for the delay. Regarding inspecting the contents of the array controller, I tried this but no file got created:
`arrayController's arrangedObjects()'s writeToFile:"~/ArrayControllerContents.plist" atomically:true`. As for [KVO compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) I'm not sure. But since a list of AppleScript records works in your test project it sounds like it is KVO compliant. Would you please post a link to your test project? I’d love to compare what you’ve done to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `tableViewData` doesn't change but `content of arrayController` does. Try

```
repeat with thisRecord in content of arrayController
    display alert "adName: " & (adName of thisRecord as  string) & return & "pageNumber: " & (pageNumber of thisRecord as  string)
end repeat
```

To make it work, use a [Script Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-BAJJCIAA) instead of a record.

```
on makeAd(nameOfAd, pageNr)
    script ad
        property adName: nameOfAd
        property pageNumber: pageNr
    end script
    return ad
end makeAd

on initTableView()
    set my tableViewData to {makeAd("C21 ad", "001"), makeAd("ERA ad", "002")}
end initTableView
```